# Material UI zoom animate out then remove

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a dynamic interface where a user can add and remove a dynamic number of items. There is an add button, and each item has a remove button. I have each item contained in a `Zoom` to give it some animation. When adding a new item, this works well. I run into issue when I delete the item, as it unrenders the item from the DOM and the animation is lost. Is there a sort of callback on the transitions that I could use to update the array containing the items after it has been animated out? Or possibly a better solution?

I have outline two possible attempts at achieving this, but both come with their issues. The first attempt leaves me with the items not animating when being removed and the second attempt leaves me with gaps where they once were (note: the grid is a desired component of my design)

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/l2lly078kq

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Zoom from "@material-ui/core/Zoom/Zoom";

let itemCount = 0;

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      items2: [],
      hiddenItems: []
    };
  }

  handleAddItem = () => {
    let items = this.state.items;
    items.push(`Item ${itemCount++}`);
    this.setState({ items });
  };

  handleDeleteItem = index => {
    let items = this.state.items;
    items.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ items });
  };

  handleAddItem2 = () => {
    let items2 = this.state.items2;
    items2.push(`Item ${itemCount++}`);
    this.setState({ items2 });
  };

  handleDeleteItem2 = index => {
    let hiddenItems = this.state.hiddenItems;
    hiddenItems.push(index);
    this.setState({ hiddenItems });
  };

  render() {
    const { items, items2, hiddenItems } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Typography>
          Items animate in, but instantly are removed instead of animating out
        </Typography>
        <Button onClick={this.handleAddItem}>Add</Button>
        <Grid container spacing={16}>
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <Zoom in={true}>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Paper>
                  <Button onClick={() => this.handleDeleteItem(index)}>
                    Delete
                  </Button>
                  {item}
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
            </Zoom>
          ))}
        </Grid>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Typography>
          Items animate in and out, but the grid does not collapse
        </Typography>
        <Button onClick={this.handleAddItem2}>Add</Button>
        <Grid container spacing={16}>
          {items2.map((item, index) => (
            <Zoom in={!hiddenItems.includes(index)}>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Paper>
                  <Button onClick={() => this.handleDeleteItem2(index)}>
                    Delete
                  </Button>
                  {item}
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
            </Zoom>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following link

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1v36zr2m94)

I have changed your code as following

```js
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Zoom from "@material-ui/core/Zoom/Zoom";

let itemCount = 0;

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      items2: [],
      hiddenItems: [],
      hiddenItems2: []
    };
  }

  handleAddItem = () => {
    let items = this.state.items;
    items.push(`Item ${itemCount++}`);
    this.setState({ items });
  };

  handleDeleteItem = index => {
    let hiddenItems = this.state.hiddenItems;
    hiddenItems.push(index);
    this.setState({ hiddenItems });

    // let items = this.state.items;
    // items.splice(index, 1);
    // this.setState({ items });
  };

  handleAddItem2 = () => {
    let items2 = this.state.items2;
    items2.push(`Item ${itemCount++}`);
    this.setState({ items2 });
  };

  handleDeleteItem2 = index => {
    let hiddenItems2 = this.state.hiddenItems2;
    hiddenItems2.push(index);
    this.setState({ hiddenItems2 });
  };

  render() {
    const { items, items2, hiddenItems, hiddenItems2 } = this.state;

    if (hiddenItems.length > 0) {
      console.log(hiddenItems);

      setTimeout(() => {
        let items = this.state.items;
        for (var item of hiddenItems) {
          items.splice(item, 1);
        }

        this.setState({ hiddenItems: [], items });
      }, 250);
    }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Typography>
          Items animate in, but instantly are removed instead of animating out
        </Typography>
        <Button onClick={this.handleAddItem}>Add</Button>
        <Grid container spacing={16}>
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <Zoom in={!hiddenItems.includes(index)}>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Paper>
                  <Button onClick={() => this.handleDeleteItem(index)}>
                    Delete
                  </Button>
                  {item}
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
            </Zoom>
          ))}
        </Grid>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Typography>
          Items animate in and out, but the grid does not collapse
        </Typography>
        <Button onClick={this.handleAddItem2}>Add</Button>
        <Grid container spacing={16}>
          {items2.map((item, index) => (
            <Zoom in={!hiddenItems2.includes(index)}>
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Paper>
                  <Button onClick={() => this.handleDeleteItem2(index)}>
                    Delete
                  </Button>
                  {item}
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
            </Zoom>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: solves exactly what i was looking for. It's too bad there's no callback way of doing it.. having to maintain two lists of visible vs hidden could get quite cumbersome. But thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `onExited` callback (The material-ui transitions are built on the react transition group Transition - See docs here http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-onExited) prop of the `Zoom` component to remove the item from the items array after the Zoom transition has finished, with the button click starting the transition. Eg:

```
<Zoom
    in={this.state.deletedItem !== item}
    onExited={() => this.handleDeleteItem(item)}
>

<Button onClick={() => this.handleRemoveItem(item)}>
```

As you can see from the code I've also:

- Removed the `hiddenItems` array and simply store the current item being deleted - `in={this.state.deletedItem !== item}`.

You can view my version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-booth-fnwwk

This approach also lets you reverse the transition if the delete fails (if for example you call an API on delete) as the transition and delete events are separated. See the following code for an example https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-babbage-y506f.

Answer (score 2):

In [Material UI Zoom Api](https://material-ui.com/ru/api/zoom/) has link to [Transition props](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-props) as supplied. In they try ["unmountOnExit"](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-unmountOnExit) prop, that

> By default the child component stays mounted after it reaches the 'exited' state. Set unmountOnExit if you'd prefer to unmount the component after it finishes exiting.

This prop use in [official examples](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/buttons/FloatingActionButtonZoom.js) with Zoom